# how to get name of the countries by latitude and longitude from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv file with longitudes and latitudes, my tasks are:

1. extract EU countries from this file
2. extract GROW sensors that are located in EU countries

My code with mistakes is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="http")
EU={'Austria',  'Belgium',  'Bulgaria',  'Croatia',  'Cyprus', 'Czechia', 'Denmark', 
'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece Hungary', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Latvia', 
'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Malta', 'Netherlands', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 
'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Sweden'}
locations = pd.read_csv('GrowLocations.csv')
locations = pd.DataFrame(locations, columns=['Latitude', 'Longitude'])
locations = locations.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
locations.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
locations = locations[(locations['Latitude']>-90) & (locations['Latitude']<90)]
locations = locations[(locations['Longitude']>-180) & (locations['Longitude']<180)]
locations.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
lats = locations['Latitude'].to_list()
lons = locations['Longitude'].to_list()
coords = list(zip(lons, lats))
countries = []
for i in range(len(coords)):
location = geolocator.reverse(coords[i], language='en')
location = location.raw
address = location.get('address')
country = address.get('country', '')
if country in EU:
   countries = pd.DataFrame(data=country, columns=['Address'])
print(countries)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data in table/code form and expected results?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18K4U0YMtJhw-ufzxC_-hSN4zQJuiez2J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In the comment above I add my file

Comment: Result I would like get like dataframe  with Name of country, Lat, Lon and grow sensor

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.